# Server not found in Kerberos database -ERR_S_PRINCIPLE_UNKNOWN(7)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I am setting up kerberos authentication for one application. Active directory is installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am generating keytab file on a centos machine which is not added to domain.

I can successfully test generated keytab file with following command

```
kinit -k -t /tmp/hirosrv.keytab hirosrv@HIRO.COM
```

Security event created on windows machine is:

> A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.
>
> Account Information:  Account Name:       hirosrv     Supplied Realm
>   Name: HIRO.COM    User ID:            HIRO\hirosrv
>
> Service Information:  Service Name:       krbtgt  Service ID:     HIRO\krbtgt
>
> Network Information:  Client Address:     10.XX.XX.2  Client Port:        37142
>
> Additional Information:   Ticket Options:     0x40800000  Result
>   Code:     0x0     Ticket Encryption Type: 0x17    Pre-Authentication Type:    2
>
> Certificate Information:  Certificate Issuer Name:            Certificate
>   Serial Number:        Certificate Thumbprint:
>
> Certificate information is only provided if a certificate was used for
>   pre-authentication.

Following is the output of `klist -A`

```
    Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: hirosrv@HIRO.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
12/03/18 16:26:48  12/04/18 02:26:48  krbtgt/HIRO.COM@HIRO.COM
    renew until 12/10/18 16:26:48
```

Same service principal is associated with user account:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> setspn.exe -Q krbtgt/HIRO.COM
Checking domain DC=hiro,DC=com
CN=hirosrv,CN=Users,DC=hiro,DC=com
        krbtgt/HIRO.COM
        krbtgt/HIRO.COM@HIRO.COM

Existing SPN found!
```

Application is configured to use the keytab file for authentication but I am getting the following error:

```
ERR_S_PRINCIPLE_UNKNOWN(7) error.
```

Comment: Does the application retrieve the Principal name from the keytab file or is this a configuration option. If it's the latter, which Principal name is configured?

Comment: What wa the command you used to generate the keytab file on the centos machine?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr In application configuration I have to define the path of keytab file, so my guess is application picks Principal name from keytab.

Comment: @T-Heron I have used **ktuti**l with `addent -password -p username@MYDOMAIN.COM -k 1 -e RC4-HMAC `

Comment: Something is wrong here.  I don't see how you can generate a keytab file on a machine which is not added to domain.  You need a secure channel with the KDC to make the keys.  It's not going to trust you otherwise.  Create the keytab on the Domain Controller, then copy the keytab over.

Comment: I have configured krb5.conf file on client and I have followed the  steps at [link](http://www.itadmintools.com/2011/07/creating-kerberos-keytab-files.html)

Comment: As long as you get a TGT when running kinit with the keytab file, the keytab file is correct. Which application are you using? Maybe the docs would tell me more.

Comment: You said "Application is configured to use the keytab file for authentication".  How do Kerberos-aware clients find the application on the network, meaning, what's the service principal name they are using to find it?